# Change a columns values in dataframe pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

I have 2 dataframes in Spark which are train and test. I have a categorical column in both, say `Product_ID`, what I want to do is that, I want to put `-1` value for those categories, which are in test but not present in train.
So for that I first found distinct categories for that column in `p_not_in_test`. But I am not able proceed further. how to do that.....

```
p_not_in_test = test.select('Product_ID').subtract(train.select('Product_ID'))

p_not_in_test  = p_not_in_test.distinct()
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a reproducible example, first we create dummy data:

```
test = sc.parallelize([("ID1", 1,5),("ID2", 2,4),
                       ("ID3", 5,8),("ID4", 9,0),
                       ("ID5", 0,3)]).toDF(["PRODUCT_ID", "val1", "val2"])

train = sc.parallelize([("ID1", 4,7),("ID3", 1,4),
                        ("ID5", 9,2)]).toDF(["PRODUCT_ID", "val1", "val2"])
```

Now we need to extend your definition of `p_not_in_test` so we get a list as an output:

```
p_not_in_test = (test.select('PRODUCT_ID')
                 .subtract(train.select('PRODUCT_ID'))
                 .rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect())
```

Finally, we can create an `udf` that will add `"-1"` in front of each `ID` that's not present in `train`.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

addString = udf(lambda x: '-1 ' + x if x in p_not_in_test else x, StringType())

test.withColumn("NEW_ID",addString(test["PRODUCT_ID"])).show()
+----------+----+----+------+
|PRODUCT_ID|val1|val2|NEW_ID|
+----------+----+----+------+
|       ID1|   1|   5|   ID1|
|       ID2|   2|   4|-1 ID2|
|       ID3|   5|   8|   ID3|
|       ID4|   9|   0|-1 ID4|
|       ID5|   0|   3|   ID5|
+----------+----+----+------+
```